# Java&Consul can't get valid instance of ServiceInstance by valid service name

Tags: java, spring-cloud, consul

```java
        for (String service : discoveryClient.getServices()) {
            System.out.println(service);
            ServiceInstance choose = loadBalancerClient.choose(service);
            System.out.println(choose);
        }
```

then:

```
consul
RibbonServer{serviceId='consul', server=127.0.0.1:8300, secure=false, metadata={}}
consul-client
null
consul-consumer
null
```

I just started to learn Spring cloud and Consul, so the project is very simple. It can almost be considered that there is only dependeny of consul. And Whether Rabbion is used has no effect on the results.

you can get the consul-client and consul-consumer projects by downloading :

https://d613.top/filebedcc/static/a2a6b2b9edc7453c9c304be3d.zip  <- consul-client

https://d613.top/filebedcc/static/971dd7c827a24e8b94280b549.zip  <- consul-consumer

what should I do to get a valid instance of `ServiceInstance` of consul-client ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It works fine for me. (I added some prefixes to tell log lines apart)
```
entering hello
service: consul
instance: RibbonServer{serviceId='consul', server=127.0.0.1:8300, secure=false, metadata={}}
service: consul-client
instance: RibbonServer{serviceId='consul-client', server=192.168.68.120:20515, secure=false, metadata={secure=false}}
service: consul-consumer
instance: RibbonServer{serviceId='consul-consumer', server=192.168.68.120:20516, secure=false, metadata={secure=false}}
```
You must have other things running in consul? What does http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/services say?

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you very much! After you tell me that the project can run successfully in your computer, I guess there maybe some problems on my computer and i try to run consul.exe in Administrator mode（window 10） and now I made it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, I just used cmd to switch to the directory where consul.exe is located and then `consul.exe agent -dev`. Thanks for @spencergibb telling me that it can work normally on his computer, so I tried running consul in administrator mode, and the result was normal.